# Column alias after groupBy in pyspark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need the resulting data frame in the line below, to have an alias name "maxDiff" for the max('diff') column after groupBy. However, the below line does not makeany change, nor throw an error.

```
 grpdf = joined_df.groupBy(temp1.datestamp).max('diff').alias("maxDiff")
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use `agg` instead of calling `max` method:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import max

joined_df.groupBy(temp1.datestamp).agg(max("diff").alias("maxDiff"))
```

Similarly in Scala

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max

joined_df.groupBy($"datestamp").agg(max("diff").alias("maxDiff"))
```

or

```scala
joined_df.groupBy($"datestamp").agg(max("diff").as("maxDiff"))
```

Comment: I prefer this to the accepted answer because it doesn't require one to know in advance the name that Spark will give to the aggregated column.

Comment: You do have to be careful, as the following syntax does not work: rmse = df.groupBy('name').agg({'sqerr':'mean'}).alias('MSE')      The alias command just seems to be ignored.  But this works:  df.groupBy('name').agg(F.mean(df.sqerr).alias('MSE'))

Answer (score 44):

This is because you are aliasing the whole `DataFrame` object, not `Column`. Here's an example how to alias the `Column` only:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

grpdf = joined_df \
    .groupBy(temp1.datestamp) \
    .max('diff') \
    .select(func.col("max(diff)").alias("maxDiff"))
```

Comment: yes.. this works.. except that func. is not required

Comment: it's not if you have already imported `pyspark.sql.functions` to your script

Comment: The problem is you need to know what spark will clal the new column which might not be obvious. @zero323's anwser is better

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the answers already here, the following are also convenient ways if you know the name of the aggregated column, where you don't have to import from `pyspark.sql.functions`:

**1**

```
grouped_df = joined_df.groupBy(temp1.datestamp) \
                      .max('diff') \
                      .selectExpr('max(diff) AS maxDiff')
```

See [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr) for info on `.selectExpr()`

**2**

```
grouped_df = joined_df.groupBy(temp1.datestamp) \
                      .max('diff') \
                      .withColumnRenamed('max(diff)', 'maxDiff')
```

See [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed) for info on `.withColumnRenamed()`

This answer here goes into more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077809

Comment: **Did you try first code block?** It seems wrong. Spark can not resolve column name with mentioned ways. In your code block, spark try to find **diff** column and try to run **max** function on given set but grouped_data doesn't contain any **diff** column, it contains **temp1.datestamp and max(diff)**.

Answer (score 2):

you can use.

```
grouped_df = grpdf.select(col("max(diff)") as "maxdiff",col("sum(DIFF)") as "sumdiff").show()
```

Comment: This syntax is invalid in pysark. Testing with Version v3.1.2  produces an error. `my_df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7)], schema=list('abcd')) ; my_df.show() ;
my_df.select(sf.col('a') as ('new_a'))`  ---> produces this error:  `SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-1675925428549211>", line 5
    my_df.select(sf.col('a') as ( 'new_a'))
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`