# How to change dataframe column names in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rename

I come from pandas background and am used to reading data from CSV files into a dataframe and then simply changing the column names to something useful using the simple command:

```
df.columns = new_column_name_list
```

However, the same doesn't work in PySpark dataframes created using sqlContext.
The only solution I could figure out to do this easily is the following:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header='false', inferschema='true', delimiter='\t').load("data.txt")
oldSchema = df.schema
for i,k in enumerate(oldSchema.fields):
  k.name = new_column_name_list[i]
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header='false', delimiter='\t').load("data.txt", schema=oldSchema)
```

This is basically defining the variable twice and inferring the schema first then renaming the column names and then loading the dataframe again with the updated schema.

Is there a better and more efficient way to do this like we do in pandas?

My Spark version is 1.5.0

Answer (score 512, accepted):

There are many ways to do that:

- Option 1. Using [selectExpr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=selectexpr#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr).

  ```
   data = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("Alberto", 2), ("Dakota", 2)], 
                                     ["Name", "askdaosdka"])
   data.show()
   data.printSchema()

   # Output
   #+-------+----------+
   #|   Name|askdaosdka|
   #+-------+----------+
   #|Alberto|         2|
   #| Dakota|         2|
   #+-------+----------+

   #root
   # |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
   # |-- askdaosdka: long (nullable = true)

   df = data.selectExpr("Name as name", "askdaosdka as age")
   df.show()
   df.printSchema()

   # Output
   #+-------+---+
   #|   name|age|
   #+-------+---+
   #|Alberto|  2|
   #| Dakota|  2|
   #+-------+---+

   #root
   # |-- name: string (nullable = true)
   # |-- age: long (nullable = true)
  ```
- Option 2. Using [withColumnRenamed](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=selectexpr#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed), notice that this method allows you to "overwrite" the same column. For Python3, replace `xrange` with `range`.

  ```
   from functools import reduce

   oldColumns = data.schema.names
   newColumns = ["name", "age"]

   df = reduce(lambda data, idx: data.withColumnRenamed(oldColumns[idx], newColumns[idx]), xrange(len(oldColumns)), data)
   df.printSchema()
   df.show()
  ```
- Option 3. using
  [alias](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.alias.html), in Scala you can also use [as](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column).

  ```
   from pyspark.sql.functions import col

   data = data.select(col("Name").alias("name"), col("askdaosdka").alias("age"))
   data.show()

   # Output
   #+-------+---+
   #|   name|age|
   #+-------+---+
   #|Alberto|  2|
   #| Dakota|  2|
   #+-------+---+
  ```
- Option 4. Using [sqlContext.sql](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.sql), which lets you use SQL queries on `DataFrames` registered as tables.

  ```
   sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(data, "myTable")
   df2 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT Name AS name, askdaosdka as age from myTable")

   df2.show()

   # Output
   #+-------+---+
   #|   name|age|
   #+-------+---+
   #|Alberto|  2|
   #| Dakota|  2|
   #+-------+---+
  ```

Comment: I did it with a `for` loop + `withColumnRenamed`, but your `reduce` option is very nice :)

Comment: @FelipeGerard that is a very bad idea

Comment: Well since nothing gets done in Spark until an action is called on the DF, it's just less elegant code... In the end the resulting DF is exactly the same!

Comment: @FelipeGerard Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066231/stack-overflow-while-processing-several-columns-with-a-udf), bad things may happen if you have many columns.

Comment: That happens when you use `withColumn` many times. I used `withColumnRenamed` just like you, but iterated with a loop instead of a `reduce`. I'll bet you the DF is the exact same one if you do `for idx in range(n): data = data.withColumnRenamed(oldColumns[idx], newColumns[idx])` than what you posted :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127333/discussion-between-felipe-gerard-and-alberto-bonsanto).

Comment: hi @Alberto Bonsanto, Thanks for your answer. Using your withColumnRenamed() answer I receive a mistake: "NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined". Sure I am missing something trivial.

Comment: @NuValue, you should first run `from functools import reduce`

Comment: Hi @AlbertoBonsanto thank you great answer. I have a 3K+ rows dataframe and my code is inspired from your reduce solution, however it seems to run forever, do you know which one I should use for my use case? (nb: i also have 2K+ columns)

Comment: I found the solution: use df.toDF(*new_cols) instead of weird reduce

Comment: In PySpark 2.4 with Python 3.6.8 the only method that works out of these is `df.select('id').withColumnRenamed('id', 'new_id')` and `spark.sql("SELECT id AS new_id FROM df")`

Comment: At python 3.7 I recommend Option 3. it work flawlessly (option 1 and 2 has some issues ex.: library places moved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689184/nameerror-name-reduce-is-not-defined-in-python )

Comment: I think I'll use this `df.selectExpr(*["{0} as {0}_other".format(x) for x in df.columns])` to rename all the columns at once (I'll be doing a `crossJoin` with itself)

Comment: Option 2: use `range()` instead of `xrange()` for Python 3.*

Comment: option 2 works for me. IMO option 2 is the best if you want to rename all your columns.

Comment: Option 3 is the right way to do it in spark (scala/python). Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62728542/8551891

Answer (score 300):

```
df = df.withColumnRenamed("colName", "newColName")\
       .withColumnRenamed("colName2", "newColName2")
```

Advantage of using this way: With long list of columns you would like to change only few column names. This can be very convenient in these scenarios. Very useful when joining tables with duplicate column names.

Comment: is there a variant of this solution that leaves all other columns unchanged? with this method, and others, only the explicitly named columns remained (all others removed)

Comment: +1 it worked fine for me, just edited the specified column leaving others unchanged and no columns were removed.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl This command appears to change only the specified column while maintaining all other columns. Hence, a great command to rename just one of potentially many column names

Comment: @user989762: agreed; my initial understanding was incorrect on this one...!

Comment: This is great for renaming a few columns.  See my answer for a solution that can programatically rename columns.  Say you have 200 columns and you'd like to rename 50 of them that have a certain type of column name and leave the other 150 unchanged.  In that case, you won't want to manually run `withColumnRenamed` (running `withColumnRenamed` that many times would also be inefficient, [as explained here](https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015)).

Answer (score 120):

If you want to change all columns names, try `df.toDF(*cols)`

Comment: this solution is the closest to df.columns = new_column_name_list per the OP, both in how concise it is and its execution.

Comment: For me I was getting the header names from a pandas dataframe, so I just used `df = df.toDF(*my_pandas_df.columns)`

Comment: This answer confuses me. Shouldn't there be a mapping from old column names to new names? Does this work by having `cols` be the new column names, and just assuming the the order of names in `cols` corresponds to the column order of the dataframe?

Comment: @rbatt Using `df.select` in combination with `pyspark.sql.functions col-method` is a reliable way to do this since it maintains the mapping/alias applied & thus the order/schema is maintained after the rename operations. Checkout the comment for code snippet:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62728542/8551891

Answer (score 80):

In case you would like to apply a simple transformation on all column names, this code does the trick: (I am replacing all spaces with underscore)

```
new_column_name_list= list(map(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "_"), df.columns))

df = df.toDF(*new_column_name_list)
```

Thanks to @user8117731 for `toDf` trick.

Comment: This code generates a simple physical plan that's easy for Catalyst to optimize.  It's also elegant.  +1

Answer (score 21):

`df.withColumnRenamed('age', 'age2')`

Comment: [Pankaj Kumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36302241) and [Alberto Bonsanto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077809) (which are from 2016 and 2015, respectively) already suggest using `withColumnRenamed`.

Comment: Thanks, yes but there are a couple of different syntax's, maybe we should collect them into a more formal answer? 

data.withColumnRenamed(oldColumns[idx], newColumns[idx]) 
vs 
data.withColumnRenamed(columnname, new columnname)

i think it depends on which version of pyspark your using

Comment: This is not a different syntax. The only difference is you did not store your column names in an array.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to rename a single column and keep the rest as it is:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
new_df = old_df.select(*[col(s).alias(new_name) if s == column_to_change else s for s in old_df.columns])
```

Answer (score 18):

this is the approach that I used:

create pyspark session:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('changeColNames').getOrCreate()
```

create dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = [('Bob', 5.62,'juice'),  ('Sue',0.85,'milk')], schema = ["Name", "Amount","Item"])
```

view df with column names:

```
df.show()
+----+------+-----+
|Name|Amount| Item|
+----+------+-----+
| Bob|  5.62|juice|
| Sue|  0.85| milk|
+----+------+-----+
```

create a list with new column names:

```
newcolnames = ['NameNew','AmountNew','ItemNew']
```

change the column names of the df:

```
for c,n in zip(df.columns,newcolnames):
    df=df.withColumnRenamed(c,n)
```

view df with new column names:

```
df.show()
+-------+---------+-------+
|NameNew|AmountNew|ItemNew|
+-------+---------+-------+
|    Bob|     5.62|  juice|
|    Sue|     0.85|   milk|
+-------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 14):

I made an easy to use function to rename multiple columns for a pyspark dataframe, 
in case anyone wants to use it:

```
def renameCols(df, old_columns, new_columns):
    for old_col,new_col in zip(old_columns,new_columns):
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(old_col,new_col)
    return df

old_columns = ['old_name1','old_name2']
new_columns = ['new_name1', 'new_name2']
df_renamed = renameCols(df, old_columns, new_columns)
```

> Be careful, both lists must be the same length.

Comment: Nice job on this one. A bit of overkill for what I needed though. And you can just pass the df because `old_columns` would be the same as `df.columns`.

Answer (score 11):

Another way to rename just one column (using `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`):

```
df = df.select( '*', F.col('count').alias('new_count') ).drop('count')
```

Answer (score 11):

**Method 1:**

```
df = df.withColumnRenamed("old_column_name", "new_column_name")
```

**Method 2:**
If you want to do some computation and rename the new values

```
df = df.withColumn("old_column_name", F.when(F.col("old_column_name") > 1, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.col("old_column_name"))
df = df.drop("new_column_name", "old_column_name")
```

Comment: There was a lot of similar answers so no need to post another one duplicate.

Comment: The first argument in withColumnRenamed is the old column name. Your Method 1 is wrong

Answer (score 6):

we can use col.alias for renaming the column:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.select(['vin',col('timeStamp').alias('Date')]).show()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following function to rename all the columns of your dataframe.

```
def df_col_rename(X, to_rename, replace_with):
    """
    :param X: spark dataframe
    :param to_rename: list of original names
    :param replace_with: list of new names
    :return: dataframe with updated names
    """
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    mapping = dict(zip(to_rename, replace_with))
    X = X.select([F.col(c).alias(mapping.get(c, c)) for c in to_rename])
    return X
```

In case you need to update only a few columns' names, you can use the same column name in the replace_with list

To rename all columns

```
df_col_rename(X,['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

To rename a some columns

```
df_col_rename(X,['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'y', 'z'])
```

Comment: I like that this uses the select statement with aliases and uses more of an "immutable" type of framework. I did, however, find that the `toDF` function and a list comprehension that implements whatever logic is desired was much more succinct. for example, `def append_suffix_to_columns(spark_df, suffix): return spark_df.toDF([c + suffix for c in spark_df.columns])`

Comment: Since `mapping` is a dictionary, why can't you simply use `mapping[c]` instead of `mapping.get(c, c)`?

Answer (score 4):

We can use various approaches to rename the column name.

First, let create a simple DataFrame.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("x", 1), ("y", 2)], 
                                  ["col_1", "col_2"])
```

Now let's try to rename col_1 to col_3. PFB a few approaches to do the same.

```
# Approach - 1 : using withColumnRenamed function.
df.withColumnRenamed("col_1", "col_3").show()

# Approach - 2 : using alias function.
df.select(df["col_1"].alias("col3"), "col_2").show()

# Approach - 3 : using selectExpr function.
df.selectExpr("col_1 as col_3", "col_2").show()

# Rename all columns
# Approach - 4 : using toDF function. Here you need to pass the list of all columns present in DataFrame.
df.toDF("col_3", "col_2").show()
```

Here is the output.

```
+-----+-----+
|col_3|col_2|
+-----+-----+
|    x|    1|
|    y|    2|
+-----+-----+
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

A way that you can use 'alias' to change the column name:

```
col('my_column').alias('new_name')
```

Another way that you can use 'alias' (possibly not mentioned):

```
df.my_column.alias('new_name')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put into for loop, and use zip to pairs each column name in two array.

```
new_name = ["id", "sepal_length_cm", "sepal_width_cm", "petal_length_cm", "petal_width_cm", "species"]

new_df = df
for old, new in zip(df.columns, new_name):
    new_df = new_df.withColumnRenamed(old, new)
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to use a dict to rename the df.

```
rename = {'old1': 'new1', 'old2': 'new2'}
for col in df.schema.names:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(col, rename[col])
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single column rename, you can still use toDF(). For example,

```
df1.selectExpr("SALARY*2").toDF("REVISED_SALARY").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches you can use:

1. `df1=df.withColumn("new_column","old_column").drop(col("old_column"))`
2. `df1=df.withColumn("new_column","old_column")`
3. `df1=df.select("old_column".alias("new_column"))`

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension + f-string:

```py
df = df.toDF(*[f'n_{c}' for c in df.columns])
```

Simple list comprehension:

```py
df = df.toDF(*[c.lower() for c in df.columns])
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is:

```
for col, new_col in columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(col, new_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType

CreatingDataFrame = [("James","Sales","NY",90000,34,10000),
    ("Michael","Sales","NY",86000,56,20000),
    ("Robert","Sales","CA",81000,30,23000),
    ("Maria","Finance","CA",90000,24,23000),
    ("Raman","Finance","CA",99000,40,24000),
    ("Scott","Finance","NY",83000,36,19000),
    ("Jen","Finance","NY",79000,53,15000),
    ("Jeff","Marketing","CA",80000,25,18000),
    ("Kumar","Marketing","NY",91000,50,21000)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("employee_name",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("department",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("state",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("age", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("bonus", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])

 
OurData = spark.createDataFrame(data=CreatingDataFrame,schema=schema)

OurData.show()

# COMMAND ----------

GrouppedBonusData=OurData.groupBy("department").sum("bonus")


# COMMAND ----------

GrouppedBonusData.show()


# COMMAND ----------

GrouppedBonusData.printSchema()

# COMMAND ----------

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

BonusColumnRenamed = GrouppedBonusData.select(col("department").alias("department"), col("sum(bonus)").alias("Total_Bonus"))
BonusColumnRenamed.show()

# COMMAND ----------

GrouppedBonusData.groupBy("department").count().show()

# COMMAND ----------

GrouppedSalaryData=OurData.groupBy("department").sum("salary")

# COMMAND ----------

GrouppedSalaryData.show()

# COMMAND ----------

from pyspark.sql.functions import col

SalaryColumnRenamed = GrouppedSalaryData.select(col("department").alias("Department"), col("sum(salary)").alias("Total_Salary"))
SalaryColumnRenamed.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method. The following method can allow you rename columns of multiple files

Reference: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/pyspark-methods-rename-columns-kyle-gibson/

```
df_initial = spark.read.load('com.databricks.spark.csv')
    
    rename_dict = {
      'Alberto':'Name',
      'Dakota':'askdaosdka'
    }
    
    df_renamed = df_initial \
    .select([col(c).alias(rename_dict.get(c, c)) for c in df_initial.columns])

    
     rename_dict = {
       'FName':'FirstName',
       'LName':'LastName',
       'DOB':'BirthDate'
        }

     return df.select([col(c).alias(rename_dict.get(c, c)) for c in df.columns])


df_renamed = spark.read.load('/mnt/datalake/bronze/testData') \
.transform(renameColumns)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is using `withColumnRenamed`:

```
renamed_df = df.withColumnRenamed(‘name_1’, ‘New_name_1’).withColumnRenamed(‘name_2’, ‘New_name_2’)
renamed_df.show()
```

**And if you would like to do this like we do with Pandas, you can use `toDF`:**

> Create an order of list of new columns and pass it to `toDF`

```
df_list = ["newName_1", “newName_2", “newName_3", “newName_4"]
renamed_df = df.toDF(*df_list)
renamed_df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to rename multiple columns with a loop:

```
cols_to_rename = ["col1","col2","col3"]

for col in cols_to_rename:
  df = df.withColumnRenamed(col,"new_{}".format(col))
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest statement to `df.columns = new_column_name_list` is:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.select(*[F.col(name_old).alias(name_new) 
                 for (name_old, name_new) 
                 in zip(df.columns, new_column_name_list)]
```

This doesn't require any rarely-used functions, and emphasizes some patterns that are very helpful in Spark. You could also break up the steps if you find this one-liner to be doing too many things:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
column_mapping = [F.col(name_old).alias(name_new) 
                  for (name_old, name_new) 
                  in zip(df.columns, new_column_name_list)]
df = df.select(*column_mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply any generic function on the spark dataframe columns and then rename the column names, can use the quinn library. Please refer example code:

```
import quinn
def lower_case(col):
  return col.lower()

df_ = quinn.with_columns_renamed(lower_case)(df)
```

lower_case is the function name and df is the initial spark dataframe

If you get an error importing quinn library. Use example code below:

```
%pip install quinn
```