# pyspark AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'toDF'

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

The following code worked for me before, but not anymore. I got the error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'toDF'

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  sc = SparkContext(appName="test")
  sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

  df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').\
    options(header='false',delimiter=',',inferSchema='true').load('test')

  ### rename columns
  df = df.toDF('a','b','c')
  ...
  sc.stop()
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: assign the column names to a data frame

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change dataframe column names in pyspark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077353/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark)

Comment: I am aware of that post. I am just thinking 'toDF' is more convenient and it worked for me before. https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Comment: I figured it out. Looks like it has to do with our spark version. It worked with 1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Looks like it has to do with our spark version. It worked with 1.6

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with spark version 1.6 then use this code for conversion of rdd into df

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
```

if you want to assign title to rows then use this

```
df= rdd.map(lambda p: Row(ip=p[0], time=p[1], zone=p[2]))
```

ip,time,zone are row headers in this example.