# string manipulation for column names in pyspark

Tags: regex, pyspark, udf

This artcle gives a great overview on how to change columnnames. 
[How to change dataframe column names in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077353/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark)

Nontheless I need something more / slightly adjusted that I am not capable of doing. Can anybody help remove spaces from all colnames? Its needed for e.g. join commands and the systematic approach reduces the effort of dealing with 30 columns. I suppose a combination of regex and a UDF would work best.

Example:
root
 |-- CLIENT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Branch Number: string (nullable = true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a real simple solution:

```
for name in df.schema.names:
  df = df.withColumnRenamed(name, name.replace(' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you want to rename multiple columns using the same column name concatenated with a prefix (or suffix)

```
df.select([f.col(c).alias(PREFIX + c) for c in columns])
```