# How to prefix columns names of dataframe efficiently without creating a new dataframe in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pandas you can rename all columns in one go in a "inplace" manner using

```
new_column_name_list =['Pre_'+x for x in df.columns]
df.columns = new_column_name_list
```

Can we do the above same step in Pyspark without having to finally create new dataframe? It is inefficient because we will have 2 dataframe with the same data but different column names leading to bad memory utlilization.

The below link answers the question but its not inplace.

[How to change dataframe column names in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077353/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark)
EDIT
My question is clearly different from the question in above link

Comment: Please read my question again. I have clearly mentioned how tha question is different from what I am asking.

Comment: The answers in the linked question, seems to answer your question, e.g. `data = data.select(col("Name").alias("name"), col("askdaosdka").alias("age"))`

Comment: No it doesnt because a new dataframe is created

Comment: Aliasing creates a new `DataFrame` object, but it doesn't create a copy of the data. Unless you're worrying about local driver memory (in that case there is no good news for you) this is a duplicate.

Comment: This will do                                                                                                           
       **left_cols = df.columns**
       '**df = df.selectExpr([col + ' as left_' + col for col in left_cols])**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could do it in **scala spark** 
Create a map of new `column` and old `column` name dynamically and select with alias.

```
val to = df2.columns.map(col(_))

val from = (1 to to.length).map( i => (s"column$i"))

df2.select(to.zip(from).map { case (x, y) => x.alias(y) }: _*).show
```

Previouse column names

```
"age", "names"
```

After changed

```
"column1". "column2"
```

However dataframe cannot be updated since they are immutable, But can bes assigned to new one for the further use. Only used dataframes are loaded in memory so this won't be issue.

Hope this helps

Comment: Based on the above code we cannot rename on the existing dataframe itseft right?  We will have to final say df3=df2.select(to.zip(from).map { case (x, y) => x.alias(y) }: _*) to make the change permananent

Comment: Will df2=df2.select(to.zip(from).map { case (x, y) => x.alias(y) }: _*) work?

Comment: This wont work because spark df is immutable?

Comment: Yes it changes the column name at once but does not changes in the original dataframe it returns a new dataframe, since the dataframe are immutable.