# pyspark column name afer pivot

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

On input I have DF similar to:

`+-----+-----+
|data1|data2|
+-----+-----+
|  1.0| 0.33|
|  1.0|    0|
|  2.0| 0.33|
|  1.0|    0|
|  1.0| 0.33|
|  2.0| 0.33|
+-----+-----+`

after performing pivot

```
pivot = df.groupBy('data1').pivot('data2').count()
```

structure looks like this:

`+-----+----+----+
|data1|   0|0.33|
+-----+----+----+
|  1.0|   2|   2|
|  2.0|null|   2|
+-----+----+----+`

Attempting to do anything with column 0.33 results in

```
AnalysisException: Can't extract value from 0#1535L;
```

How to handle this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your column name contains a dot. As you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14736):

> The Spark SQL doesn’t support field names that contains dots

**Solution 1**

Rename columns with new names (new names have to be without dots):

There are many ways to do this, see this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077353/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark), here I have put an example from that question:

```
>>> oldColumns = pivot.schema.names
>>> newColumns = ["data1","col1","col2"]
>>> newPivot = reduce(lambda data, idx: data.withColumnRenamed(oldColumns[idx], newColumns[idx]), xrange(len(oldColumns)), pivot)
>>> newPivot.show()
+-----+----+----+
|data1|col1|col2|
+-----+----+----+
|  1.0|   2|   2|
|  2.0|null|   2|
+-----+----+----+
```

**Solution 2**

Use backquote ( ` ) to select the column that have dots in its name (here an example):

```
>>> newPivot = pivot.groupBy().sum("`0.33`")
>>> newPivot.show()
+---------+
|sum(0.33)|
+---------+
|        4|
+---------+
```