# How to transform rdd to dataframe in pyspark 1.6.1?

Tags: pyspark, rdd

Any examples on how to transform rdd to dataframe and transform dataframe back to rdd in pyspark 1.6.1?
`toDF()` can not be used in 1.6.1?

For example, I have a rdd like this:

```
data = sc.parallelize([('a','b','c', 1,4), ('o','u','w', 9,3), ('s','q','a', 8,6), ('l','g','z', 8,3), \
                       ('a','b','c', 9,8), ('s','q','a', 10,10), ('l','g','z', 20,20), ('o','u','w', 77,77)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you can't use .toDF() method cannot, the solution I propose is this:

```
data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([('a','b','c', 1,4), ('o','u','w', 9,3), ('s','q','a', 8,6), ('l','g','z', 8,3), \
                   ('a','b','c', 9,8), ('s','q','a', 10,10), ('l','g','z', 20,20), ('o','u','w', 77,77)]))
```

This will create a DF with names "_n" where n is the number of the column. If you want to rename the columns I suggest that you look this post: [How to change dataframe column names in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077353/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark). But all you need to do is:

```
data_named = data.selectExpr("_1 as One", "_2 as Two", "_3 as Three", "_4 as Four", "_5 as Five")
```

Now let's see the DF:

```
data_named.show()
```

And this will output:

```
+---+---+-----+----+----+
|One|Two|Three|Four|Five|
+---+---+-----+----+----+
|  a|  b|    c|   1|   4|
|  o|  u|    w|   9|   3|
|  s|  q|    a|   8|   6|
|  l|  g|    z|   8|   3|
|  a|  b|    c|   9|   8|
|  s|  q|    a|  10|  10|
|  l|  g|    z|  20|  20|
|  o|  u|    w|  77|  77|
+---+---+-----+----+----+
```

EDIT: Try again, because you should be able to use .toDF() in spark 1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a reason why `rdd.toDF` cannot be used in pyspark for spark 1.6.1. Please check spark 1.6.1 python docs for example on `toDF()`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext

As per your requirement,

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('a','b','c', 1,4), ('o','u','w', 9,3), ('s','q','a', 8,6), ('l','g','z', 8,3), ('a','b','c', 9,8), ('s','q','a', 10,10), ('l','g','z', 20,20), ('o','u','w', 77,77)])

#rdd to dataframe
df = rdd.toDF() 
## can provide column names like df2 = df.toDF('col1', 'col2','col3,'col4') 

#dataframe to rdd
rdd2 = df.rdd
```