# rename columns in dataframe pyspark adding a string

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have written code in Python using Pandas that adds "VEN_" to the beginning of the column names:

```
Tablon.columns = "VEN_" + Tablon.columns
```

And it works fine,  but now I'm working with PySpark and it doesn't work.
I've tried:

```
Vaa_total.columns = ['Vaa_' + col for col in Vaa_total.columns]
```

or

```
for elemento in Vaa_total.columns:
    elemento = "Vaa_" + elemento
```

And other things like that but it doesn't work.

I don't want to replace the columns name, I just want to mantain it but adding a string to the beginning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change dataframe column names in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077353/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark)

Comment: I don't think so, there is explained how to replace it but I don't know how I can to add a string to my columns name, I get: AttributeError: can't set attribute.

Comment: look into option 2 or 3. It's exactly what you need.

Comment: yes, you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for elemento in Vaa_total.columns:
    Vaa_total =Vaa_total.withColumnRenamed(elemento, "Vaa_" + elemento)
```

Answer (score 0):

I linked similar topic in comment.
Here's example adapted from that topic to your task:

```
dataframe.select([col(col_name).alias('VAA_' + col_name) for col_name in dataframe])
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard format of writing it:

```
renamed_df = df.withColumnRenamed(col_name, "insert_text" + col_name) for col_name in dataframe.columns])
```

Comment: There is a bracket missing somewhere in your solution