# AWS Glue Multi-column rename on DynamicFrames

Tags: aws-glue

Documentation doesn't specify if this is allowed or not however I can't seem to get it to work and it isn't very clean to chain multiple DF's over and over.

E.g.

```
    df1= RenameField.apply(frame = df, old_name = "col1",new_name = "COL1")
df2= RenameField.apply(frame = df1, old_name = "col2", new_name = "COL2")
```

I tried a few variants and based on other Glue transforms thought the following would have worked..

```
df1 = RenameField.apply[(frame = df, old_name = "col1",new_name = "COL1"),
                       (frame = df, old_name = "col2", new_name = "COL2")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `applyMapping` method from DynamicFrame to rename columns and/or cast to another data type (Scala):

```
val mappedDynamicFrame = sourceDynamicFrame.applyMapping(
      mappings = Seq(
        ("col1", "string", "column_1", "string"),
        ("col2", "string", "column_2", "string"),
        ("col3", "long", "column_3", "timestamp")
      ),
      caseSensitive = false,
      transformationContext = s"mapped-source"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write clean chain code if you accept conversion like ... "DynamicFrame -> DataFrame -> DynamicFrame". DynamicFrame class has conversion methods; [toDF and fromDF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html). I mean, it's better to do renaming on Dataframe class. In order to use PySpark Dataframe class, you can use conversion methods of toDF & fromDF.

PySpark Dataframe class has several column renaming methods, see [How to change dataframe column names in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077353/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename_field`. `rename_field` can convert using the chain method.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-rename_field

example is below.

```py
df1 = df1.rename_field("id", "org_id").rename_field("name", "org_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method that I used:

```
    # Create a new DynamicFrame with renamed columns
    for c_old, c_new in zip(old_column_names, new_column_names):
        dyf = dyf.rename_field(f"`{c_old}`", c_new)
```

Note: You'll need the backticks if the old column name has a period in it :)