# how to rename column name of dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I want to rename one column name from dataframe columns, So currently the Column name is `rate%year`. I want to rename it as `rateyear` in `pyspark`.

Possibly, we can rename columns at dataframe and table level after registering dataframe as table, but at table level "%" will create problem so i want to rename at dataframe level itelf.

I tried this- `data.selectExpr("rate%year as rateyear")`

but getting this error `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'rate' given input columns`

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change dataframe column names in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077353/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark)

Comment: @Matt B, I went through the links and tried this-  data.selectExpr("rate%year as rateyear") but getting this error pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`rate`' given input columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible way of renaming at dataframe level-

```
oldColumns=['rate%year']
newColumns = ["rateyear"]
df1 = reduce(lambda df, idx: df.withColumnRenamed(oldColumns[idx], newColumns[idx]), xrange(len(oldColumns)), df)
```

this is working fine at dataframe level. any suggestion how to resolve at table level?

Comment: Just rename the column prior to registering the dataframe as a table e.g.  `df = df.withColumnRenamed('rate%year', 'rateyear')` and then `sc.registerDataFrameAsTable(data, "myTable")` no need for reduce and lambdas

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(data, "myTable")
data = sqlContext.sql("SELECT rate%year AS rateyear from myTable")
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an easy and fast function for you to remove % from column names. Enjoy! :)

```
def rename_cols(rename_df):
    for column in rename_df.columns:
        new_column = column.replace('%','')
        rename_df = rename_df.withColumnRenamed(column, new_column)
    return rename_df
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and quick way to alter dataframe column names.

```
def format_col(df):    
    cols = [col.replace("%", "") for col in df.columns]
    res_df = df.toDF(*cols)
    return res_df
```