# How to drop a column from a spark dataframe by index where column names can be duplicated?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe and want to drop only the last column.

I tried

```
df.drop(df.columns.last)`
```

but got error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'last'`.

I also tried:

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[-1])
```

but this dropped all columns with that has same name as last.

Using Spark 2.4

Comment: It is better to drop by name. `withColumn` can alter the order of the columns

Comment: @Joe I would recommend the following: 1) Save the column names to a list: `colnames = df.columns` 2) rename the columns so the names are unique: `df = df.toDF(*range(colnames))` 3) drop the last column `df = df.drop(df.columns[-1])` 4) rename the columns back to the original: `df = df.toDF(*cols[:-1])`. Ping me if the question is reopened and I will post an answer.

Comment: @pault I reopened the question

Answer (score 4):

It is better to drop a column by name. Some operation like `withColumn` can alter the order of the columns. If a dataframe has duplicate names coming out from a join then refer the column by `dataframe.column_name` instead of referring it by `"columnName"` which causes ambiguity.

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.c1 == df2.c1).drop(df2.c1)
```

In general `df.drop(df.columnName)`

Comment: Column name could be ambiguous since there will be 2 columns with name `c1` here.

Comment: if I do `df2.drop('C1')` then its ambiguous. But if I do `df2.drop(df2.C1)` then it is not. Please try.

Comment: I will need example and spark version to reproduce.

Comment: If the df has multiple columns with the same name and are thus ambiguous, this doesn't work. This is a circumstantial answer that works after this particular join.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach you can take to drop any column by index.

Suppose you had the following DataFrame:

```
np.random.seed(1)
data = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(3,3))

df = spark.createDataFrame(data.astype(int).tolist(), ["a", "b", "a"])
df.show()
#+---+---+---+
#|  a|  b|  a|
#+---+---+---+
#|  5|  8|  9|
#|  5|  0|  0|
#|  1|  7|  6|
#+---+---+---+
```

First save the original column names.

```
colnames = df.columns
print(colnames)
#['a', 'b', 'a']
```

Then [rename all of the columns in the DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44382252/5858851) using `range` so the new column names are unique (they will simply be the column index).

```
df = df.toDF(*map(str, range(len(colnames))))
print(df.columns)
#['0', '1', '2']
```

Now drop the last column and rename the columns using the saved column names from the first step (excluding the last column).

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[-1]).toDF(*colnames[:-1])
df.show()
#+---+---+
#|  a|  b|
#+---+---+
#|  5|  8|
#|  5|  0|
#|  1|  7|
#+---+---+
```

You can easily expand this to any index, since we renamed using `range`.

---

I broke it up into steps for explaination purposes, but you can also do this more compactly as follows:

```
colnames = df.columns
df = df.toDF(*map(str, range(len(colnames))))\
    .drop(str(len(colnames)-1))\
    .toDF(*colnames[:-1])
```