# Merging csv files but the files may have different column names

Tags: python, dataset, merging-data

I wish to combine csv files into one dataset. Each file has a different column name.
How do I change the column names to a standard one and merge them.

if all the columns names in the file were standard, I could use a list comprehension to combine them:

```py
df = pd.concat(pd.read('list', usecols=['col1','col2','col3'])
    for list in glob.glob('data/data*.csv')
```

but my datasets have different column names.

Comment: You can rename columns in a dataframe, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077353/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark) addresses that.