# Spark sql group by and sum changing column name?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In this data frame I am finding total salary from each group. In Oracle I'd use this code

```
select job_id,sum(salary) as "Total" from hr.employees group by job_id;
```

In Spark SQL tried the same, I am facing two issues

```
empData.groupBy($"job_id").sum("salary").alias("Total").show()
```

1. The alias total is not displaying instead it is showing "sum(salary)" column
2. I could not use `$` (I think Scala SQL syntax). Getting compilation issue

   ```
    empData.groupBy($"job_id").sum($"salary").alias("Total").show()
   ```

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column alias after groupBy in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516490/column-alias-after-groupby-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Aggregate function `.agg()` if you want to provide alias name. This accepts scala syntax ($" ")

```
empData.groupBy($"job_id").agg(sum($"salary") as "Total").show()
```

If you dont want to use `.agg()`, alias name can be also be provided using `.select()`:

```
empData.groupBy($"job_id").sum("salary").select($"job_id", $"sum(salary)".alias("Total")).show()
```