# How to use group by with sum, with many columns, without renaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have DataFrame like this(bat with 200 columns +):

```
uid sel_type1 sel_type2 sel_type3
123 1         0         1
123 1         1         0
100 0         1         2
```

and after i use

```
df.groupBy(col("uid")).sum()
```

i have something like this:

```
uid sum(sel_type1) sum(sel_type2) sum(sel_type3)
123 2              1              1
100 0              1              2
```

Bat i wont this:

```
uid sel_type1 sel_type2 sel_type3
123 2         1         1
100 0         1         2
```

How can i do it?

Comment: this question didn't help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516490/column-alias-after-groupby-in-pyspark]

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35593002/19032206):

```
df.groupBy(col("uid")).sum().toDF(df.columns:_*)
```